# The top grout line in the shower wall tile is about 2 inches. How can it be fixed?

Tags: shower, tile, grout

I just had my old bathtub/shower insert replaced with a tub insert and the walls tiled to the ceiling.  When it was "finished" the grout line from the ceiling to the top of the tile is about 2 inches.  I know this will not last, so my question is, now that I have paid for all of this, how can I go back behind them and make it right?

Comment: 2" is not a grout line. It's an epic fail. (So is naming yourself after your fleeting state of mind, incidentally. :P )

Comment: @Disappointed Call that company back out and have them fix it! Cal and Call again - whatever it takes to get that right. Post Pictures of their work on Craigslist , angies list , yelp, bbb and wherever if that is what it takes to get them to come back out and Fix it.

Comment: Crown molding the bathroom might be an option

Answer (score 2):

Don't pay them until they come back and do it right, but since you're asking I'm guessing you've paid already.

To fix, you'd need to get a wet saw or tile cutter and some of the tiles used in the project. Scrape out the grout, cut tile to 2" minus width of your grout lines minus 1/8" to 1/4". Put the tile up with mortar, grout, and caulk along the top where it meets the ceiling.

Comment: You can easily remove the grout using a oscillating saw with a fresh bit! Best investment I've ever made at Harbor Freight.

Comment: You don't need matching tile - an accent strip may be easier.